# NSInvocation with an enum?

Tags: ios, cocoa, cocoa-touch, enums, nsinvocation

**------------ EDIT -------------**

TL;DR:

It seems I used the NSInvocation class incorrectly (lacking pointer knowledge).

The way to use those would be like so (Works):

```
NSString *str = @"string";
UIControlState state = UIControlStateNormal;
[invocation setArgument: &str atIndex: 2];
[invocation setArgument: &state atIndex: 3];
```

**--------------- Original Question ---------**

Is it possible to `setArgument:atIndex:` with an enum argument?

See the following example (that doesn't work):

```
UIButton *btn = ...;
SEL selector = @selector(setTitle:forState:);
NSInovcation *invocation = [NSInovcation invocationWithMethodSignature: [btn methodSignatureForSelector: selector]];
[invocation setSelector: selector];
[invocation setArgument: @"Test" atIndex: 2];

//Nothing happens
UIControlState state = UIControlStateNormal;
[invocation setArgument: &state atIndex: 3];

//Runtime error (the pointer is NULL)
UIControlState *state = UIControlStateNormal;
[invocation setArgument: state atIndex: 3];

//No errors but no effect
int state2 = 0;
[invocation setArgument: &state atIndex: 3];

//Compile error (casting)
[invocation setArgument: @(UIControlStateNormal) atIndex: 3];
//Runtime EXC_BAD_ACCESS
[invocation setArgument: (void *)@(UIControlStateNormal) atIndex: 3];

...
[invocation invokeWithTarget: btn];
```

Strangely (or not), it does work well with `performSelector:...`:

```
[btn performSelector: selector withObject: @"Testing" withObject:@(UIControlStateNormal)];
```

I'm not sure I'm using NSInovcation the correct way. Anyone would like to elaborate?

Comment: Using `@(...)` wraps the enum value in an `NSNumber`. Clarify what you mean by "doesn't work". Compile error? Runtime error? Unexpected behavior? Be specific.

Comment: Compile time error for casting, casting it to `void *` doesn't give any errors it just does nothing. I assume it does not behave like `performSelector` does.

Comment: I haven' used NSInvocation, however, the selector you're trying to invoke only has 2 arguments. I see that you're using indexes: 2 and 3. Should they not be 0 and 1?

Comment: Following the NSInvocation documentation, arguments 0 and 1 are `self` and `_cmd`

Comment: Ah ok, makes sense. I forgot those are implicit.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this:

```js
NSString *test = @"Test";
[invocation setArgument: &test atIndex: 2];

UIControlState state = UIControlStateNormal;
[invocation setArgument: &state atIndex: 3];
```

Comment: See above as part of my question I've added an answer, but thanks for making a formal answer.